# Removing matched object from array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of 4 objects and each object contains property array of 8 object.

[image]

[image]

I am trying to remove an object from properties Array[8]

```
        var responseArray = new Array();
        responseArray = response.data;
         responseArray.forEach(function (resProp) {
            if (resProp.alias == "General Details") {
                resProp.properties.forEach(function (checkProp) {

                    if (checkProp.alias == "name") {
                        responseArray.pop(checkProp);
                    }
                });
            }

        });
```

I am able to pop it however the responseArray having only 3 object Array instead of 4.i think, this code is removing the whole 4th object.

```
responseArray.pop(checkProp);
```

any suggestions on removing only matched object?

Comment: please add the object in text form.

Comment: see docs [Array.prototype.pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pop method is not suitable to remove specific object from an array

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns that element.

- You should remove object from `responseArray.properties` array instead of `responseArray`

Replace  `responseArray.pop(checkProp);` with  `resProp.properties.splice( resProp.properties.indexOf(checkProp) , 1 );`

Comment: i tried its not working.i think it need to splice from responseArray as its the only which is defined however getting "indexOf is not defined"

Comment: @Harshit Oh, my bad, sure you would get that error, indexOf does not have a context. I updated my answer try it now.

Comment: great.thanks a lot :) its working.just concern on the compatibility of indexOf operator.is there a other way to get the index?

Comment: good point, `indexOf` is supported from IE9 +, if that is still matter , you could iterate thru `resProp.properties` using `for` loop instead of `forEach` and for current element (for which you have index too) pass that index to `splice` method as a first parameter.