# Remove matched object from deeply nested array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a data tree structure with children:

```
{  id: 1,
   name: "Dog",
   parent_id: null,
   children: [
         {
             id: 2,
             name: "Food",
             parent_id: 1,
             children: []
         },
         {
             id: 3,
             name: "Water",
             parent_id: 1,
             children: [
                 {
                    id: 4,
                    name: "Bowl",
                    parent_id: 3,
                    children: []
                 },
                 {
                    id: 5,
                    name: "Oxygen",
                    parent_id: 3,
                    children: []
                 },
                 {
                    id: 6,
                    name: "Hydrogen",
                    parent_id: 3,
                    children: []
                 }
             ]
         }
   ]
}
```

This represents a DOM structure that a user could select an item from to delete by clicking the corresponding button in the DOM.

I have a known text title of the selected item for deletion from the DOM set as the variable clickedTitle. I am having trouble finding an algorithm that will allow me to delete the correct object data from the deeply nested tree.

Here is my code:

```
function askUserForDeleteConfirmation(e) {
    const okToDelete = confirm( 'Are you sure you want to delete the item and all of its sub items?' );
    if(!okToDelete) {
        return;
    }
    const tree = getTree(); // returns the above data structure
    const clickedTitle = getClickedTitle(e); // returns string title of clicked on item from DOM - for example "Dog" or "Bowl"
    const updatedTree = removeFromTree(tree, tree, clickedTitle);

    return updatedTree;
}

function removeFromTree(curNode, newTree, clickedTitle) {
    if(curNode.name === clickedTitle) {
        // this correctly finds the matched data item to delete but the next lines don't properly delete it... what to do?
        const index = curNode.children.findIndex(child => child.name === clickedTitle);
        newTree = curNode.children.slice(index, index + 1);
        // TODO - what to do here?
    }

    for(const node of curNode.children) {
        removeFromTree(node, newTree, clickedTitle);
    }

    return newTree;
}
```

I have tried to use the info from [Removing matched object from array of objects using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446531/removing-matched-object-from-array-of-objects-using-javascript) without success.

Comment: Could you provide what would be the desired result in the application of the function for an example case?

Comment: having both checks of `curNode.name === clickedTitle` and `child => child.name === clickedTitle` doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Exacty, that´s why I am asking for an example of the desired effect

Comment: the desired result is to remove the item from the original tree.

Comment: ggorlen's answer worked without any issues. Victor's answer did seem to work but the application wasn't working out, was causing weird behaviors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind modifying the parameter tree [in-place](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), this should do the job. Note that it'll return `null` if you attempt to remove the root.

```js
const tree = { id: 1, name: "Dog", parent_id: null, children: [ { id: 2, name: "Food", parent_id: 1, children: [] }, { id: 3, name: "Water", parent_id: 1, children: [ { id: 4, name: "Bowl", parent_id: 3, children: [] }, { id: 5, name: "Oxygen", parent_id: 3, children: [] }, { id: 6, name: "Hydrogen", parent_id: 3, children: [] } ] } ] };

const removeFromTree = (root, nameToDelete, parent, idx) => {
  if (root.name === nameToDelete) {
    if (parent) {
      parent.children.splice(idx, 1);
    }
    else return null;
  }
  
  for (const [i, e] of root.children.entries()) {
    removeFromTree(e, nameToDelete, root, i);
  }
  
  return tree;
};

console.log(removeFromTree(tree, "Oxygen"));
```

Your current code is very much on the right track. However:

```
newTree = curNode.children.slice(index, index + 1);
```

highlights a few issues: we need to manipulate the parent's `children` array to remove `curNode` instead of `curNode`'s own `children` array. I pass parent objects and the child index recursively through the calls, saving the trouble of the linear operation `findIndex`.

Additionally, slicing from `index` to `index + 1` only extracts one element and doesn't modify `curNode.children`. It's not obvious how to go about using `newArray` or returning it through the call stack. `splice` seems like a more appropriate tool for the task at hand: extracting one element in-place.

Note that this function will delete multiple entries matching `nameToDelete`.

Answer (score 2):

I like @VictorNascimento's answer, but by applying `map` then `filter`, each `children` list would be iterated twice. Here is an alternative with `reduce` to avoid that:

```
function removeFromTree(node, name) {
  return node.name == name
    ? undefined
    : {
        ...node,
        children: node.children.reduce(
          (children, child) => children.concat(removeFromTree (child, name) || []), [])
      }
}
```

In the case you want a way to remove the items in-place, as @ggorlen proposed, I'd recommend the following solution, that is simpler in my opinion:

```
function removeFromTree(node, name) {
  if (node.name == name) {
    node = undefined
  } else {
    node.children.forEach((child, id) => {
      if (!removeFromTree(child, name)) node.children.splice(id, 1)
    })
  }
  return node
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've built the algorithm as follows:

```
function omitNodeWithName(tree, name) {
  if (tree.name === name) return undefined;

  const children = tree.children.map(child => omitNodeWithName(child, name))
    .filter(node => !!node);

  return {
    ...tree,
    children
  }  
}
```

You can use it to return a new tree without the item:

```
noHydrogen = omitNodeWithName(tree, "Hydrogen")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's ok to use Lodash+[Deepdash](https://deepdash.io/#filterdeep), then:

```
let cleaned = _.filterDeep([tree],(item)=>item.name!='Hydrogen',{tree:true});
```

Here is a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/yurigor/pen/gEGwrY?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0):

We use [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan) for many data processing tasks. It's powerful once you wrap your head around it. Here is how you could answer your question

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const prune = (name, input) => objectScan(['**[*]'], {
  rtn: 'bool',
  abort: true,
  filterFn: ({ value, parent, property }) => {
    if (value.name === name) {
      parent.splice(property, 1);
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
})(input);

const obj = { id: 1, name: 'Dog', parent_id: null, children: [{ id: 2, name: 'Food', parent_id: 1, children: [] }, { id: 3, name: 'Water', parent_id: 1, children: [{ id: 4, name: 'Bowl', parent_id: 3, children: [] }, { id: 5, name: 'Oxygen', parent_id: 3, children: [] }, { id: 6, name: 'Hydrogen', parent_id: 3, children: [] }] }] };

console.log(prune('Oxygen', obj)); // return true iff pruned
// => true

console.log(obj);
// => { id: 1, name: 'Dog', parent_id: null, children: [ { id: 2, name: 'Food', parent_id: 1, children: [] }, { id: 3, name: 'Water', parent_id: 1, children: [ { id: 4, name: 'Bowl', parent_id: 3, children: [] }, { id: 6, name: 'Hydrogen', parent_id: 3, children: [] } ] } ] }
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@13.8.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)